# Is there a way to call built-in sql function in Linq to Entities

Tags: linq, built-in, sql-function

I want to know if there is a way to call built-in sql functions in LINQ to Entities? Such as `'CAST'`, `'ISNULL'`. I have searched on the internet and I know how to call user-defined functions in LINQ to Entities, but I don't know how to call built-in functions. Certainly, some built-in functions can be instead by CLR method, but I'll appreciate if you have a way to call them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SqlFunctions Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) - Provides common language runtime (CLR) methods that call functions in the database in LINQ to Entities queries.

**How to use**

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities AWEntities = new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    // SqlFunctions.CharIndex is executed in the database.
    var contacts = from c in AWEntities.Contacts
                   where SqlFunctions.CharIndex("Si", c.LastName) == 1
                   select c;

    foreach (var contact in contacts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(contact.LastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pranay Rana, thanks for your reply! But my initial post states I know how to call custom function, what I really want to know is how to call built-in function, such as 'CAST', 'ISNULL'.

Comment: @James - check the SqlFunctions class link in given in my answer which support some built in functions...